# Google Apps Script find value and set value not working

Tags: google-apps-script

Context is Google Sheets. My script is supposed to find a cell in column A with contents `Cell 1` and then set the B and C columns in that row to `Cell 2` and `Cell 3`. Unfortunately, despite rechecking this many times, I can't seem to get it to work.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
for (var i = 1; i<sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
  var value = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
  if (value == "Cell 1") {
    sheet.getRange(i, 2).setValue("Cell 2");
    sheet.getRange(i, 3).setValue("Cell 3");
  }
}
```

Can you help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, at `for (var i = 1; i<sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {}`, there is `i<sheet.getLastRow()`. This means that the value of last row is not retrieved. So please modify

#### From :

```
for (var i = 1; i<sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
```

#### To :

```
for (var i = 1; i<=sheet.getLastRow(); i++) {
```

or

```
for (var i = 1; i<sheet.getLastRow() + 1; i++) {
```

#### Other sample :

As an other sample, you can also achieve it using `getValues()` and `setValues()`. The sample script is as follows.

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var values = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
var modified = values.map(function(e){return e[0] == "Cell 1" ? [e[0], "Cell 2", "Cell 3"] : [e[0], "", ""]});
sheet.getRange(1,1,modified.length,modified[0].length).setValues(modified);
```

#### References :

- [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)
- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I like your mapping setup. I always forget about mapping. In the process, I found an error on my part that was part of a larger script, but it appears that my original version worked, I just made a mistake elsewhere. Anyway, I'm now using yours and thankfully after nearly a whole day my project is complete! I thought it would only take a couple hours. Sheesh. THANK YOU

Comment: @BarryMode I'm glad your problem was solved. Thank you, too.